# What are main advantages "Administration Tools - Package Item" over Package Designer?

Tags: admin-pages

Just for curiosity want to know more detail about  `Administration Tools - Package Item`. It mentions **include** item reference,presentation details and workflow etc.

Please give more details about advantages of this utility over `Package Designer`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Package Item` tools can be used to generate packages of items with their **dependencies**.

Unlike the `Package Designer` wizard accessible from through the `Desktop` though, the UI here is much more limited but the tool will package the dependencies of an item as well: all item references, presentation items if you’re using `Webforms`, custom assemblies, `workflow items` and `templates`. Very useful for creating packages of pages for distribution.

**Note:** This page(`admin/PackageItem.aspx`) makes Sitecore package of the specified item and puts it into the `/temp` folder.

**Reference:** https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/sitecore-admin-pages-cheat-sheet-new-tools/